# How Paypal Recurring payment active with Paypal Advance Payment Pro in C#?

Tags: paypal

I want to integrate the Recurring payment with PayPal Advance payment Pro in C#. We are getting the response when we creating the recurring profile but we didn't see the profile and also it not charged to the customers. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Shaival,

I'm assuming you're trying to create a recurring payment with the direct credit card using PayPal payment pro API. To know more [Check PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/recurring-payments/).

To resolve the issue, follow the below steps:

1. For sample code, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/recurring-payments/#create-a-recurring-payments-profile)

Check the PayPal API response, if it has ACK=SUCESS then it will give you a **PROFILE_ID**, **PROFILE STATUS** with other details and PayPal will charge the buyer automatically on your given **PROFILESTARTDATE**.

You could also check the recurring profile details in the Merchant as well as buyer's PayPal account activity page.

2. If it has ACK=Failure, then check for error message or contact [PayPal MTS](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) for better assistance